# Отсутствует перевод заголовка "Code of Conduct" в справке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, нормы-поведения

На странице [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/) отсутствует перевод заголовка раздела "Code of Conduct":

> [image: справка]

В transifex такая строка тем не менее переведена (ключ: `16b552ae6488376b26790dd873ae3a1f`). На [испаноязычном SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/) перевод присутствует:

> [image: испанская справка]

Comment: А что за отвёртка?

Comment: @Qwertiy вообще-то это булавка. Модераторам не показывается?

Comment: Показывается. Я просто не в курсе, что она означает там. На испанском же нет её.

Comment: @Qwertiy видимо, испанцы не любят булавки. А может это какое-то непристойное изображение для них :)

Comment: @Qwertiy [вот](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183318/339911)

Comment: Во-первых, я в принципе не знал, что там порядок записей меняется. Во-вторых, у нас с итальянцами же одновременно появился code of conduct (как и на других сайтах сети) - почему тогда у нас иконка есть, а у них нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy с какими ещё итальянцами? :) У испанцев вообще нет булавок почему-то везде.

Comment: Тьфу, перепутал. Так у нас всего одна булавка. Если у них её нет, то вот и закончились. Зато у них перевод есть)

Comment: @Qwertiy посмотрите на других сайтах, там вообще всё в булавках. Что и стога сена не найдёшь.

Comment: @alexolut Запостил на MSE баг про булавки https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314285/346987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправил!

Единственное, есть нюанс. В справочной системе под этим заголовком лежит целая не переведенная страница. Как перейти на нее, не понятно. На всякий случай ниже ее содержимое на английском языке. Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь переводить напрямую в этом ответе.

---

This Code of Conduct helps us build a community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect. Whether you’ve come to ask questions or to generously share what you know, join us in building a community where all people feel welcome and can participate, regardless of expertise or identity.

We commit to enforcing and improving the Code of Conduct. It applies to everyone using Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network, including our team, moderators, and anyone posting to Q&A sites or chat rooms.

## Our Expectations

- If you’re here to get help, make it as easy as possible for others to help you. [Follow our guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and remember that our community is made possible by volunteers.
- If you’re here to help others, be patient and welcoming. Learning how to participate in our community can be hard. Offer support if you see someone struggling or otherwise in need of help.
- Be clear and constructive when giving feedback, and be open when receiving it. Edits, comments, and suggestions are healthy parts of our community.
- Be kind and friendly. Avoid sarcasm and be careful with jokes — tone is hard to decipher online. If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on.

### Unacceptable Behavior

- No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language. Even if you don’t intend it, this can have a negative impact on others.
- No name-calling or personal attacks. Focus on the content, not the person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (e.g. “lazy”).
- No bigotry. We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. When in doubt, just don’t.
- No harassment. This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.

### Reporting

Every person contributes to building a kind, respectful community. If you find unacceptable behavior directed at yourself or others, you can:

- [Flag](/help/flagging) the harmful content. Depending on the content, flagging will alert moderators or trigger an automatic deletion.
- [Contact us](/contact). We’ll respond as quickly as we can.

We take your reports seriously. Those who don’t follow the Code of Conduct in good faith may face repercussions deemed appropriate by our moderation team. This is how moderators generally handle misconduct:

### Enforcement

#### Warning

For most first-time misconduct, moderators will remove offending content and send a warning. Most issues are resolved here.

#### Account Suspension

For repetitive misconduct or behavior containing harassment, bigotry, or abuse, moderators will impose a temporary suspension (one day or more, depending on the violation).

#### Account Expulsion

For very rare cases, moderators will expel people who display a pattern of harmful destructive behavior toward our community.

All actions will be taken on a case-by-case basis at the discretion of our moderators. If you have concerns about how a moderator has handled a situation, [contact us](/contact) directly.

We created this Code of Conduct because it reinforces the respect that we, as a community, expect from one another. Having a code also provides us with clear avenues to correct our culture should it stray off-course.

We welcome your feedback on this and every other aspect of what we do at Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network. Thank you for working with us to build a kind, collaborative, and respectful community.

This text incorporates ideas and language from the Coral Project, Buffer, and Tech Solidarity codes of conduct.

Comment: "Как перейти на нее, не понятно" даже прямой ссылки нет? Видимо стоит баг-репорт оформить.

Comment: @älёxölüt Я такой ссылки не нашел.

Comment: Так это же [переведено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: @älёxölüt И да, и нет. Страница норм переводится через Transifex/Traducir. Текст выше находится во внутренней системе переводов. Тексты никак не пересекаются.

Comment: Я побайтово, конечно, не сравнивал, но текст, имхо, один в один повторяет [англоязычные нормы](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).