# Отсутствует перевод в справке: I've thought better of my question; can I delete it? Code of Conduct

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

На странице [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help) отсутствует перевод строк *I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?* и *Code of Conduct*

Кроме этого, на странице [*I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) отсутствует перевод.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7680/15479