# Убрать из справки повторяющиеся пункты, ведущие на CoC

Tags: дефект, предложение, справка, нормы-поведения

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что [Нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/conduct), что [Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) ведут на [CoC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Предлагаю убрать [Будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) из списка, т.к. смысла в этом пункте нет никакого.

Comment: О, кто-то читает справку)))

Comment: @Qwertiy ну не модератору же её читать!

Comment: Вероятно, связано с [этим](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8322/176217).

Comment: @älёxölüt раньше там нормальная(почти) статья была https://web.archive.org/web/20160121225031/https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice, теперь редирект на CoC.

Comment: @Qwertiy иногда кажется, что только я и читаю =/

Comment: @Suvitruf понятно, что была, когда был бинайс, но потом случился филанизий, и бинайс умер, родив из своего компоста КоК. Просто ссылку забыли убрать, посмотрите, например на enSO, там нет такого.